# Apache Kafka: Configuring `ListSerde` for `TopologyTestDriver`

Tags: java, kotlin, apache-kafka

I am writing a unit test for a custom suppress. The class is called `SupressProcessor`. The unit test looks like:

```kotlin
import io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDeConfig
import no.statnett.observations.grid.flow.CorridorFlow.avro.v1.CorridorFlow
import my.stream.SuppressProcessor
import my.stream.TopicSerdeConfig
import org.apache.kafka.clients.CommonClientConfigs
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig
import org.apache.kafka.streams.Topology
import org.apache.kafka.streams.TopologyTestDriver
import org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.api.ProcessorSupplier
import org.apache.kafka.streams.state.Stores
import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestInstance
import testUtils.RecordFactory
import java.time.Duration
import java.util.Properties

@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
class SuppressProcessorTests {

    // Following https://www.ru-rocker.com/2020/12/07/how-to-unit-test-kafka-streams-application-part-2-processor-api/

    private lateinit var topology: Topology
    private lateinit var testDriver: TopologyTestDriver

    private val schemaRegistryScope = SuppressProcessorTests::class.java.name
    private val schemaRegistryUrl = "mock://$schemaRegistryScope"

    private val inputTopicName = "input_topic"
    private val outputTopicName = "output_topic"
    private val topicSerde = TopicSerdeConfig(inputTopicName, outputTopicName, schemaRegistryUrl)

    private val sourceName = "source"
    private val processorName = "suppress-processor"
    private val stateStoreName = "suppress-processor-store"

    private val recordFactory = RecordFactory()

    @BeforeEach
    fun setup() {
        val config = Properties()
        config[StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG] = "suppress-processor-test"
        config[StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG] = ""
        config[StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG] = topicSerde.stringKeySerde::class.java
        config[StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG] = "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes.ListSerde"
        config[CommonClientConfigs.DEFAULT_LIST_VALUE_SERDE_INNER_CLASS] = topicSerde.inputValueSerde.javaClass
        config[AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG] = schemaRegistryUrl

        val storeBuilder = Stores
            .timestampedKeyValueStoreBuilder(
                Stores.inMemoryKeyValueStore(stateStoreName),
                topicSerde.stringKeySerde, topicSerde.corridorFlowListSerde
            )
            .withLoggingDisabled()

        topology = Topology()
        topology.addSource(sourceName, topicSerde.stringKeySerde.deserializer(), topicSerde.corridorFlowListSerde.deserializer(), inputTopicName)
        topology.addProcessor(processorName, ProcessorSupplier { SuppressProcessor(stateStoreName) },sourceName)
        topology.addStateStore(storeBuilder, processorName)
        topology.addSink("sink", outputTopicName, processorName)

        testDriver = TopologyTestDriver(topology, config)

    }

    @Test
    fun `Should schedule as expected`(){
        val inputTopic = testDriver.createInputTopic(
            inputTopicName,
            topicSerde.stringKeySerde.serializer(),
            topicSerde.corridorFlowListSerde.serializer()
        )
        val outputTopic = testDriver.createOutputTopic(
            outputTopicName,
            topicSerde.stringKeySerde.deserializer(),
            topicSerde.corridorFlowListSerde.deserializer()
        )

        val corridorFlow = recordFactory.generateCorridorFlow()
        val corridorFlows = listOf<CorridorFlow>(corridorFlow, corridorFlow)

        inputTopic.pipeInput(corridorFlow.mrid, corridorFlows)

        assertThat(outputTopic.isEmpty).isTrue

        testDriver.advanceWallClockTime(Duration.ofSeconds(3))

        assertThat(outputTopic.isEmpty).isFalse

    }
}
```

The `SupressProcessor` looks like:

```kotlin
import net.logstash.logback.marker.Markers
import my.App
import my.avro.CorridorFlow
import org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.PunctuationType
import org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.api.ContextualProcessor
import org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.api.ProcessorContext
import org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.api.Record
import org.apache.kafka.streams.state.TimestampedKeyValueStore
import org.apache.kafka.streams.state.ValueAndTimestamp
import java.time.Duration
import java.time.Instant

class SuppressProcessor(private val stateStoreName: String) :
    ContextualProcessor<String, MutableList<CorridorFlow>, String, MutableList<CorridorFlow>>() {
    private lateinit var store: TimestampedKeyValueStore<String, MutableList<CorridorFlow>>

    override fun init(context: ProcessorContext<String, MutableList<CorridorFlow>>?) {
        super.init(context)
        this.store = context().getStateStore(stateStoreName)
        context().schedule(Duration.ofSeconds(1), PunctuationType.WALL_CLOCK_TIME) { schedule() }
    }

    override fun process(record: Record<String, MutableList<CorridorFlow>>) {
        App.log.debug(
            Markers.append("SuppressedValue", record.value()),
            "Suppress received key=${record.key()} receivedAt=${context().currentSystemTimeMs()}"
        )

        store.put(record.key(), ValueAndTimestamp.make(record.value(), getExpirationTimestamp()))
    }

    private fun getExpirationTimestamp(timestamp: Long = context().currentSystemTimeMs()): Long =
        timestamp + Duration.ofSeconds(2).toMillis()

    private fun schedule(currentTimestamp: Long = context().currentSystemTimeMs()) {

        val expiredKeys = mutableListOf<String>()

        val iterator = store.all()


        iterator.forEach { aggregate ->

            App.log.info(aggregate.toString())

            App.log.info("currentTimestamp: $currentTimestamp")
            App.log.info("aggregateTimestamp: ${aggregate.value.timestamp()}")


            if (aggregate.value.timestamp() >= currentTimestamp) return@forEach

            App.log.info(aggregate.toString())

            App.log.debug(
                Markers.append("Suppress", aggregate.value),
                "Suppress release key=${aggregate.key} releasedAt=${currentTimestamp}"
            )

            val recordTimestamp = Instant.parse(aggregate.value.value().first().timeInterval.end).toEpochMilli()
            context().forward(Record(aggregate.key, aggregate.value.value(), recordTimestamp))
            expiredKeys.add(aggregate.key)
        }
        iterator.close()
        context().commit()
        expiredKeys.forEach { store.delete(it) }
    }
}
```

And the `Serde` configuration file looks like:

```kotlin
import io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDeConfig;
import io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerde;
import my.avro.BiddingZoneFlow;
import my.avro.CorridorFlow;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serde;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class TopicSerdeConfig {
  public final String inputTopic;
  public final String outputTopic;
  public final String schemaRegistryUrl;

  public final Serde<String> stringKeySerde;
  public final SpecificAvroSerde<CorridorFlow> inputValueSerde;
  public final Serde<List<CorridorFlow>> corridorFlowListSerde;
  public final SpecificAvroSerde<BiddingZoneFlow> outputValueSerde;

  public TopicSerdeConfig(String inputTopic, String outputTopic, String schemaRegistryUrl) {
    this.inputTopic = inputTopic;
    this.outputTopic = outputTopic;
    this.schemaRegistryUrl = schemaRegistryUrl;

    var serdeConfig = Collections.singletonMap(AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, schemaRegistryUrl);

    // Configure input serdes
    stringKeySerde = Serdes.String();
    stringKeySerde.configure(serdeConfig, true);

    inputValueSerde = new SpecificAvroSerde<>();
    inputValueSerde.configure(serdeConfig, false);

    // Configure aggregation serdes
    corridorFlowListSerde = Serdes.ListSerde(ArrayList.class, inputValueSerde);

    // Configure output serdes
    outputValueSerde = new SpecificAvroSerde<>();
    outputValueSerde.configure(serdeConfig, false);
  }
}
```

Note that this file is written in Java as opposed to Kotlin which is used in the other files.

When running the unit test, the following error message occurs:

```bash
rg.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid value org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes.ListSerde for configuration default.value.serde: Class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes.ListSerde could not be found.

    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parseType(ConfigDef.java:744)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parseValue(ConfigDef.java:490)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parse(ConfigDef.java:483)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.<init>(AbstractConfig.java:113)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.<init>(AbstractConfig.java:146)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig.<init>(StreamsConfig.java:1235)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ClientUtils$QuietStreamsConfig.<init>(ClientUtils.java:55)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.TopologyTestDriver.<init>(TopologyTestDriver.java:320)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.TopologyTestDriver.<init>(TopologyTestDriver.java:299)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.TopologyTestDriver.<init>(TopologyTestDriver.java:275)
    at my.SuppressProcessorTests.setup(SuppressProcessorTests.kt:66)
```

Any idea on how to configure `ListSerde` for unit tests using `TopologyTestDriver`?

EDIT: Added `pom.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>parent-poms</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.3/maven-model/maven.html#class_parent -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>application</groupId>
    <artifactId>flow-application</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>flow-application</name>
    <description>flow-application</description>

    <properties>
        <ktor.version>2.2.1</ktor.version>
        <confluent.version>7.3.0</confluent.version>
        <kafka.version>3.3.1</kafka.version>
        <prometeus.version>1.10.2</prometeus.version>
        <avro.version>1.11.1</avro.version>
        <observations-avro.version>2.0.12</observations-avro.version>
        <logback-classic.version>1.4.5</logback-classic.version>
        <logstash-logback-encoder.version>7.2</logstash-logback-encoder.version>
        <slf4j.version>2.0.6</slf4j.version>

        <!-- Test -->
        <junit-jupiter.version>5.9.1</junit-jupiter.version>
        <kotlinx-coroutines-debug.version>1.6.4</kotlinx-coroutines-debug.version>
        <assertj-core.version>3.23.1</assertj-core.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-schema-registry-client</artifactId>
            <version>${confluent.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-avro-serializer</artifactId>
            <version>${confluent.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-streams-avro-serde</artifactId>
            <version>${confluent.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-core</artifactId>
            <version>${prometeus.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
            <version>${prometeus.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
            <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
            <version>${avro.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>no.statnett.schemas.business</groupId>
            <artifactId>observations-avro</artifactId>
            <version>${observations-avro.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
            <version>${kafka.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>${kafka.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.ktor</groupId>
            <artifactId>ktor-server-core-jvm</artifactId>
            <version>${ktor.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.ktor</groupId>
            <artifactId>ktor-server-netty-jvm</artifactId>
            <version>${ktor.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.ktor</groupId>
            <artifactId>ktor-server-metrics-jvm</artifactId>
            <version>${ktor.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.ktor</groupId>
            <artifactId>ktor-server-content-negotiation-jvm</artifactId>
            <version>${ktor.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.ktor</groupId>
            <artifactId>ktor-serialization-gson-jvm</artifactId>
            <version>${ktor.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback-classic.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
            <version>${logstash-logback-encoder.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-streams-test-utils</artifactId>
            <version>${kafka.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.ktor</groupId>
            <artifactId>ktor-server-tests-jvm</artifactId>
            <version>${ktor.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlinx</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlinx-coroutines-debug</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlinx-coroutines-debug.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>${assertj-core.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Will the error disappear when you import the missing library?

Comment: May be you have to add the jar file -which contains this class- as dependency in your build process.

Comment: I have included the kafka-clients dependency and some other relevant confluent and kafka dependencies, so I  do not think the depencies are the issue?

Comment: But what **version** did you add of `kafka-clients`? It is in [3.3.1](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/3.3.1/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/Serdes.java#L129-L148). You don't need Confluent libs for `ListSerde`. Also, Avro supports array types on its own, which you can define a schema for, and just use that for `SpecificAvroSerde`

Comment: I'm using `3.3.1`, yes! It feels a little overkill to define a separate avro schema just to be able to implement a unit test. Also, the processor is defined to handle a list of `CorridorFlow` avro objects, and by defining a new schema/object I will have to make the processor more generic.

Comment: Maybe there is a version conflict of one dependency, so the ide and/or compiler are unable to find nessecary class.

Comment: I added the `pom.xml`, if it is of interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to change the config of the `TopologyTestDriver` to the following

```kotlin
val config = Properties()
        config[StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG] = "suppress-processor-test"
        config[StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG] = ""
        config[StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG] = topicSerde.stringKeySerde::class.java
        config[StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG] = topicSerde.corridorFlowListSerde.javaClass
        config[CommonClientConfigs.DEFAULT_LIST_VALUE_SERDE_TYPE_CLASS] = topicSerde.inputValueSerde.javaClass
        config[CommonClientConfigs.DEFAULT_LIST_VALUE_SERDE_INNER_CLASS] = topicSerde.inputValueSerde.javaClass
        config[AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG] = schemaRegistryUrl
```